# Does the imaginary part of a complex exponential function include the sign before it?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I am deriving some equations, but encountered a problem.

We know that $$e^{i\theta}=\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$$

, where $\cos{\theta}$ is the real part, and $\sin{\theta}$ is the imaginary part.

However, for $$e^{-i\theta}=\cos{\theta}-i\sin{\theta}$$

What is the imaginary part?

Is it $\sin{\theta}$? Or $-\sin{\theta}$?

Comment: $x-iy$ is the same thing as $x+(-y)i$, and so the imaginary part of this number is $-y$. In your example it is $-\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Thank you. How do I close this thread?

Comment: You don't close it but you can mark an answer as accepted.  This takes it off the unanswered clue.

Comment: To fully explain, $e^{-i\theta} = \cos{-\theta} + i\sin{-\theta}$. $\cos{-\theta} = \cos{\theta}$ and  $\sin{-\theta}  = -\sin{\theta}$. See section $2.1$ under [trig identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Reflections) ... basically the fact that cosine is an even function and sine is an odd function

Comment: Ah, you can't mark it as answered because you didn't receive any answers.  You only received comments.

Comment: @HalcyonMo There is a close option right above the comments. Since you didn't get any answers (just comments), you can close it without problems if you want.

Comment: If you wait for $48$ hours, you can answer your own question and then accept your own answer.  If you choose to do so, I suggest that you cite the people who helped you in the comments.

Comment: I just added an answer that also includes a series expansion (plus a spoiler), if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint #1: Subsitute $-i \theta$ in the identity $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ and note that $\cos (-\theta) = \cos (\theta)$ and $\sin (-\theta) = -\sin (\theta)$.

Hint #2 (using the series expansion for $e^x$)

Since $$e^{i\theta} = i^0 + i^1+\frac {i^2}{2!}+\frac {i^3}{3!}+\frac {i^4}{4!}+\frac {i^5}{5!}+\dots = 1 + i +\frac {1}{2!}+\frac {i}{3!}+\frac {1}{4!}+\frac {i}{5!} +\dots$$ we can separate the real and imaginary parts to get

$$(1 +\frac {1}{2!}+\frac {1}{4!} \dots) = \cos \theta$$ and $$ i(1 +\frac {1}{3!}+\frac {1}{5!} \dots) = i \sin \theta$$ thus $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.

Doing the same for $$e^{-i\theta} = i^0 + i^{-1}+\frac {i^{-2}}{2!}+\frac {i^{-3}}{3!}+\frac {i^{-4}}{4!}+\frac {i^{-5}}{5!}\dots = 1 - i +\frac {1}{2!}-\frac {i}{3!}+\frac {1}{4!}-\frac {i}{5!} \dots$$ what do you notice when you separate the real and imaginary parts?

> $$(1 +\frac {1}{2!}+\frac {1}{4!} \dots) = \cos \theta$$ and $$- i(1 +\frac {1}{3!}+\frac {1}{5!} \dots) = -i \sin \theta$$ thus $$e^{-i \theta} = \cos \theta - i \sin \theta$$